# rtcwake being set one day ahead of intended time

Tags: ubuntu, date, real-time

I am trying to use this command to wake up my computer 5 seconds from now:

```
sudo rtcwake -m no -s 5
```

The problem I am having is that the time to wake my computer is set 5 seconds ahead of current time tomorrow

The current time is

```
Mon Sep  4 21:59:50
```

But rtcwake sets the time for

```
Tue Sep  5 21:59:55
```

Am I missing something? I just want it to set the wakeup time 5 seconds away.

Comment: see hwclock and the internal rtc time